# NetSuite: Calling an API in real time as field values get updated

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm looking for a way (using SuiteScript 2.0) to handle real-time persistent (stored) field updates, where a field might have changed in NetSuite (for example a lead time was just updated), and it doesn't matter if a user saved the change, or some other automated process changed that field. I just want to be able to pick up on that change:

1. The moment that it's done, and
2. Without regard for who or what kicked it off (e.g. it could be a person, but it could also be an automated change from a workflow, or a formula on the field itself which pulls values from another field)

Doing some research I found some options that looked somewhat promising at first. One being the afterSubmit event in a client script, and the other being the fieldChanged event. My issue however is, from what I understood those only really seem to be triggered by a *user* manually going in and making those changes, but this is only one part of the puzzle and doesn't seem to cover changes made outside of the scope of the user making those changes. Is that correct however? Or would one of those events still be able to capture changes done to that field regardless of who (or what) initiated or triggered the change, and right at the moment the change was saved/ persisted to the database?

Answer (score 1):

UserEvents are basically triggers. In their deployment records you can set the context in which they fire so you can get them to fire in all circumstances (called contexts in Netsuite) but one.

That circumstance is User Events are not fired for record saves made in User Event scripts. i.e., if an AfterSubmit UserEvent script loads, changes and saves your record a fresh user event will not be fired.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for clarifying! So in that case, what would be the best way to handle any afterSubmit UserEvent scripts that might change that field? Is there maybe another workaround that might be better in that case, if it misses those sorts of updates? Other than (for example) I imagine having to go in and manually edit all afterSubmit events